# what I do for these conditions to follow FP?

Tags: function, scala, haskell, functional-programming

I'm reading FP and I have two basic questions:

1. FP says function should take one input and gives single output. So what should I do with `void` methods? It doesn't return anything right?
2. FP says function should have single
   resresponsibility, then how do we handle `log` statements inside the method? That doesn't violate the rule?

Wish to know how they handle these things in Scala, Haskell.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm assuming you're reading a book called "Functional Programming", although it would help to know who the author is as well.  In any case, these questions are relatively easy to answer and I'll give my answers with respect to Haskell because I don't know Scala.

---

> So what should I do with void methods? It doesn't return anything right?

There are no `void` methods in a pure functional language like Haskell.  A pure function has no side effects, so a pure function without a return value is meaningless, something like

```hs
f :: Int -> ()
f x = let y = x * x + 3 in ()
```

won't do any computation, `y` is never calculated and all inputs you give will return the same value.  However, if you have an impure function, such as one that writes a file or prints something to the screen then it must exist in a *monadic context*.  If you don't understand monads yet, don't worry.  They take a bit to get used to, but they're a very powerful and useful abstraction that can make a lot of problems easier.  A monad is something like `IO`, and in Haskell this takes a type parameter to indicate the value that can be stored inside this context.  So you can have something like

```hs
putStrLn :: String -> IO ()
```

Or

```hs
-- FYI: FilePath is an alias for String
writeFile :: FilePath -> String -> IO ()
```

these have side effects, denoted by the return value of `IO something`, and the `()` something means that there is no meaningful result from that operation.  In Python 3, for example, the `print` function returns `None` because there isn't anything meaningful to return after printing a value to the screen.  The `()` can also mean that a monadic context has a meaningful value, such as in `readFile` or `getLine`:

```hs
getLine :: IO String
readFile :: FilePath -> IO String
```

When writing your `main` function, you could do something like

```hs
main = do
    putStrLn "Enter a filename:"
    fname <- getLine    -- fname has type String
    writeFile fname "This text will be in a file"
    contents <- readFile fname
    putStrLn "I wrote the following text to the file:"
    putStrLn contents
```

---

> FP says function should have single resresponsibility, then how do we handle log statements inside the method? That doesn't violate the rule?

Most functions don't need logging inside them.  I know that sounds weird, but it's true.  In Haskell and most other functional languages, you'll write a lot of small, easily testable functions that each do one step.  It's very common to have lots of 1 or 2 line functions in your application.

When you actually do need to do logging, say you're building a web server, there are a couple different approaches you can take.  There is actually a monad out there called `Writer` that lets you aggregate values as you perform operations.  These operations don't have to be impure and do IO, they can be entirely pure.  However, a true logging framework that one might use for a web server or large application would likely come with its own framework.  This is so that you can set up logging to the screen, to files, network locations, email, and more.  This monad will wrap the `IO` monad so that it can perform these side effects.  A more advanced one would probably use some more advanced libraries like monad transformers or extensible effects.  These let you "combine" different monads together so you can use utilities for both at the same time.  You might see code like

```hs
type MyApp a = LogT IO a

-- log :: Monad m => LogLevel -> String -> LogT m ()

getConnection :: Socket -> MyApp Connection
getConnection sock = do
    log DEBUG "Waiting for next connection"
    conn <- liftIO $ acceptConnection sock
    log INFO $ "Accepted connection from IP: " ++ show (connectionIP conn)
    return conn
```

I'm not expecting you to understand this code fully, but I hope you can see that it has logging and network operations mixed together.  The `liftIO` function is a common one with monad transformers that "transforms" an IO operation into a new monad that wraps IO.

This may sound pretty confusing, and it can be at first if you're used to Python, Java, or C++ like languages.  I certainly was!  But after I got used to thinking about problems in this different way makes me wish I had these constructs in OOP languages all the time.

Answer (score 3):

I can answer from Haskell perspective.

> FP says function should take one input and gives single output. So what should I do with void methods? It doesn't return anything right?

Because that's what actually functions are! In mathematics, every functions takes some input and gives you some output. You cannot expect some output without giving any input. `void` methods you see in other languages doesn't make sense in a mathematical way. But in reality `void` methods in other languages do some kind of IO operations, which is abstracted as `IO` monad in Haskell.

> how do we handle log statements inside the method

You can use a monad transformer stack and lift your `IO` log operations to perform there. In fact, writer monad can do log operations purely without any `IO` activities.